# Trained Watson retrieve and rank service with 80 questions : can I create a ranker?

Tags: ibm-watson, retrieve-and-rank

I am not getting the answer from Retrieve and Rank which is a perfect match to the question( I get the perfectly matched answer in the Retrieve and Rank WebUI. The data is trained with 80 questions, creating a ranker will help in getting the perfectly matched answer ?

And can I create a ranker with only 80 questions instead of 150 questions, as stated in the documentation?

I would like to use the curl command to create a ranker using the curl command :

```
curl -X POST -u "{username}":"{password}" -F training_data=@train.csv -F training_metadata="{\"name\":\"My ranker\"}" "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/retrieve-and-rank/api/v1/rankers"
```

The problem is that I uploaded data using Web UI for Retrieve and Rank, how do I export that data to a csv file or is there any other way to create a ranker using a curl command ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the web tooling to train a ranker, it also includes running tests to give you an evaluation of the performance of that ranker. Because of this, it requires ratings for more questions - to allow for both the training and test sets.

If you only want to train a ranker with no test or evaluation of it's performance, then you can do this manually using curl commands.

There is currently no export from the web tooling, however this is something that we will be introducing soon.

Comment: Thank you, Dale. This is exactly what I learnt on exploring the APIs and Docs.